# Method Chaining equivalent?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

This is working properly (from initial testing).
Since method chaining is my preferred format, I've tried to figure out what the method chaining equivalent is, but with no luck.  Any ideas?

```
var data = (from p in db.Persons
            from c in db.Companies
            where c.CompanyName == companyName && p.CompanyId == c.CompanyId
            select p)
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Id = p.PersonId,
                Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName)
            });
```

Thanks,
--Ed

Comment: The opaque identifier is the tricky bit...

Comment: "method chaining is my preferred format": if you can write this with the query syntax but can't figure out how to tranform it to method syntax, why bother ? It's much more readable this way. Don't restrict yourself to only one syntax, in some cases one is just better than the other... Just pick the right one for the task at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would reorder the query a bit to filter out the `companyName` first, then perform the join. This would allow you to use this fluent syntax:

```
var query = db.Companies.Where(c => c.CompanyName == companyName)
              .Join(db.Persons, c => c.CompanyId, p => p.CompanyId, (p, c) => p)
              .Select(p => new
              {
                  Id = p.PersonId,
                  Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName)
              });
```

Having said that, some queries are a lot easier to write in query syntax, so why constrict yourself? Complicated joins are usually nicer in query syntax and you also get the benefit of using `SelectMany` join format with `from ... from...` instead of `join p in ... on x equals y`. See this question for more details: [When to prefer joins expressed with SelectMany() over joins expressed with the join keyword in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025871/).

Comment: That is not what the above is translated to, although it is _logically_ equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Without changing the query, something like below, where `oi` is the opaque identifier:

```
var data =  db.Persons.SelectMany(p =>  db.Companies, (p, c) => new {p,c})
    .Where(oi => oi.c.CompanyName == companyName
        && oi.p.CompanyId == oi.c.CompanyId)
    .Select(oi => oi.p)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Id = p.PersonId,
        Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName)
    });
```

However, you might also consider a few re-writes; maybe a join, or moving the company-name check earlier; and removing the double-select.

Answer (score 2):

Non-toplevel *from* clauses translate to *SelectMany* calls:

```
db.Persons.SelectMany(p => db.Companies.Select(c => new { p, c }))
```

It is non-intuitive and a little hacky (although logical and reliable). I personally tend to use the query syntax for complex queries like this one because the SelectMany form is unreadable.